# printing list members

Tags: c#, list, foreach

hopefully my last question for a while. I have a simple class that also contains a List property.

```
public class MyClass    
{
    public double myProperty1;
    public double myProperty2;
    public List<double> myList { get; private set; }

    public MyClass()
    {    
        myList = new List<double>();
    }    
}
```

in my program I create a List of MyClass object that I add to another list

```
List<MyClass> nMyClassList = new List<MyClass>();
```

all works so far. Now I have a for each loop, where i go through and change some properties of each MyClass object in nMyClassList

```
foreach (MyClass i in nMyClassList )
{
    if x = y
        i.myList.Add(y); // I think this is working fine

    if something else

    foreach (double a in i.mylist)
    {
        Print(a); // problem here
    }      
}
```

But when I print a, I apparently am printing all the doubles in the List, not just the ones associated with a single object even though my foreach is nested in the first one still. Am I doing something totally wrong here? Any ideas. I think I am adding the values correctly, perhaps it is just something with the last foreach where I am printing all the myList doubles from the whole nMyClassList ?

Comment: could you make a SSCCE, a Small Self-Contained **Complete** Example for us?

Comment: Maybe you can edit your example and explain what are you trying to acomplish in each step. Even better if you could provide a complete working example as @SamIam suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing equals sign here:

```
if x = y
```

This code assigns the value of y to x and returns true (this if block will always be executed)

Should be

```
if x == y
```

Comment: thanks, yeah I just put the simple = sign as i was writing the question fast. There is not a problem with the equation, more so with the code. But thanks